# C# Exclamation Operator On Object

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

In C# what do the following code fragments do?

1)

```
if (!object)
{
  //code
}
```

2)

```
if (object)
{
  //code
}
```

Where object is an instance of a class, and definately not `bool`.

1) In Java, trying the above code will make the compiler issue an error. Only boolean variables can be used as a Condition_Block. This works as expected.

2) In C++, `if (!object){/**/}` is used for null checks.

3) In C#, the compiler issues no error and happily compiles it. Google never mentions ! operator used to objects. It only gives search results on bool values. Furthermore to add insult to injury, it gives results of people talking about ? and ?? operators, which are operations that wont be available to unity developers for maybe 30-40 years. Only NET3.5 API is supported. If ! operator works as in C++, why do people need ? and ??.

Edit: Full code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        Foo a = new Foo();
        if (a)  Debug.Log("a");
        if (!a) Debug.Log("b");
    }
 }
```

it prints "b" on execution.

Comment: "In c#, The compiler issues no error and happily compiles it" -- not my compiler. But you refuse to say what type "object" is, so you're obviously leaving something indispensible out of your question.

Comment: P.S. `??`, `?.`, and `?:` (you make a real habit of excluding important information, don't you) *do something different*.

Answer (score 14):

**In C# there are three instances where `if (!object)`will compile:**

1. If `object` is of type `bool`
2. If an `implicit operator bool` overload has been defined for the type of `object`.
3. If the `!` operator has been overloaded for the type of `object`.

An example of overloading `!`:

```
class Test
{
    public int Value;

    public static bool operator ! (Test item)
    {
        return item.Value != 0;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Test test = new Test();
Console.WriteLine(!test); // Prints "False"

test.Value = 1;
Console.WriteLine(!test); // Prints "True"
```

**In C# there are two instances where `if (object)` will compile:**

1. If `object` is of type `bool`.
2. If an `implicit operator bool` overload has been defined for the type of `object`.

An example of `implicit operator bool`:

```
class Test
{
    public int Value;

    public static implicit operator bool(Test item)
    {
        return item.Value != 0;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Test test = new Test();

Console.WriteLine(!test); // Prints "True"

if (test)
    Console.WriteLine("This is not printed");

test.Value = 1;

Console.WriteLine(!test); // Prints "False"

if (test)
    Console.WriteLine("This is printed");
```

Comment: [EDIT] I missed out `implicit operator bool` - added to the answer.

Comment: @user2186597 The code I posted doesn't compile if you remove the implicit operator (try it!).

Comment: @user2186597 Your class derives from `MonoBehaviour` which implements `implicit operator bool`, so all is explained.